# Script can't find database

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, office-interop

I'm working on a project that converts and prints PDF files. 
While running the script I get error:

> Cannot find either column “dbo” or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate “dbo.certdate”, or the name is ambiguous

The weird thing is that the script **used** to work before. I didn't change the code, the only thing that changed is that I installed different kind of Office versions witch was necessary to make the script working. Could that make this error?  What could be the problem?

I'm using SQL server 2008 R2 and Office Enterprise 2007

Here is the db code:

```vb
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class ConnectionManager

    Public Enum DbType
        CERT = 1
        ARKIV = 2
    End Enum

    Public Sub New(ByRef _log As Logg)
        Log = _log
    End Sub

    Private _databas As DbType
    Public Property Databas As DbType
        Get
            Return _databas
        End Get
        Set(value As DbType)
            _databas = value
            If Not _connection Is Nothing Then _connection = Nothing
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Property Log As Logg
    Public ReadOnly Property ConnectionStrang As String
        Get
            Select Case Databas
                Case DbType.ARKIV
                    Return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databas.arkiv").ConnectionString
                Case DbType.CERT
                    Return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databas.cert").ConnectionString
                Case Else
                    Return ""
            End Select

        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ServerName As String
        Get
            Dim res As String = ""
            Dim start As Integer = ConnectionStrang.IndexOf("(HOST=") + 6
            Dim slut As Integer = ConnectionStrang.IndexOf(")", start)

            res = ConnectionStrang.Substring(start, slut - start)
            Return res
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _connection As SqlConnection
    Public ReadOnly Property Connection(Optional forceNew As Boolean = False) As SqlConnection
        Get
            If _connection Is Nothing Or forceNew = True Then _connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrang)
            If Not _connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then _connection.Open()
            Return _connection
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property FilePath As String
        Get
            Dim path As String = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\out"
            If IO.Directory.Exists(path) = False Then IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
            Return path & "\"
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _wrdapp As Word.Application
    Public ReadOnly Property WordApp As Word.Application
        Get
            If _wrdapp Is Nothing Then _wrdapp = New Word.Application
            Return _wrdapp
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub TestConnection()
        Try
            Dim com As New SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM sys.tables", Connection(True))
            Log.Add(com.ExecuteScalar & " tabeller hittat i " & Databas.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub



    Public Function GetReder(sql As String, Optional newConn As Boolean = False) As SqlDataReader
        Try
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, Connection(newConn))
            Return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is code that is the problem:

```
Private Function createBevakningsRegisterData(pers As String) As PDFData
    Try
        Dim r As SqlDataReader
        Dim ret As New PDFData(PDFData.vissatt.list)
        Dim sql As String = " select "
        sql &= "WATCHCODE as Kod,"
        sql &= "dbo.certdate(WATCHDATE) as [Datum &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;],"
        sql &= "WATCHTEXT as [Text],"
        sql &= "watchflag as [Påm.],"
        sql &= "WATCHREMDATE as [tom.]"
        sql &= " from CERTUSR_WATCH "
        sql &= "where PERSNR ='" & pers & "'"

    r = GetReder(sql)

    ret.Rubrik = "BEVAKNINGSREGISTER"

    Dim rowCounter As Integer = 0
    While r.Read
        For i As Integer = 0 To r.FieldCount - 1
            If rowCounter = 0 Then ret.Properties.Add(r.GetName(i))
            ret.Values.Add(r(i).ToString)
        Next
        rowCounter = 1
    End While

    r.Close()

    Return ret
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
End Try
```

End Function

Comment: You say the code used to work until you changed the version of Office, but then you say you changed the version of Office in order to make it work. That suggests that the code didn't work either before or after you changed the version of Office.

Comment: It would also be helpful if your read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The script you posted seems incomplete.  You have a single select call in there that wouldn't cause the error you're seeing - you also have a unused functoin that's trying to call `ExecuteReader()` (which could cause the error your'e seeing).  There are lots of things that could cause this though - missing/insufficient permissions on DB is  likely, or a typo in a SQL statement.

Comment: @DanField I updated my code. I'm sorry for earlier mistake. Could you please look at that code and give me your opinion?

Comment: Seems pretty likely that `dbo.certdate` calls some other proc/function you don't have access to (namely, `dbo.Splitfn`).  Check your database permissions and/or make sure `dbo.Splitfn` exists in the database.

Comment: The whole error is: `Cannot find either column “dbo” or the user-defined function or aggregate “dbo.certdate”, or the name is ambiguous`

It's not about `dbo.Splitfn`, it's about `dbo.certdate`

Comment: @DanField Check above comment. I'm sorry for giving the wrong information before.

Answer (score 0):

Check the database you're connecting to.  Connect with the same credentials as the user running the script.  Try to run `exec dbo.certdate('test')`.  You'll likely get an error, either because certdate doesn't exist or you don't have permission.  Logon as admin and create it or set the proper permissions on it.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I run the `exec dbo.certdate('test')`? Is there a special place in SQL server that I can do that or should I just write it down in the SQL query?

Comment: I think dbo.certdate is a database function, but how can I check if it exists?

Comment: SSMS would probably be the most straightforward way.  Or have your DBA do it.